# Delphi code O(x) complexity

Tags: delphi, big-o

I have found a Delphi source code from the net that I am going to use but I see that there are comments like `procedure sortList; // sorry for O(n^2) but a log(n) is impossible. gl`. Not going to post the code here, but it sorts stuff in a TList with some for loops.

I have read Marco Cantu and Nick Hodges books but I have never seen the `O(x)` thing. I have googled it and I have seen that indicates how much a procedure is fast. Is it correct?

Does delphi support this feature as well? Sorry but I have seen a lot of maths and I haven't understood very well.

Comment: Have you seen https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation?

Comment: And FWIW, O(N^2) for sorting is probably indicative of a poor algorithm choice.

Comment: O(Logn) impossible...  Indeed,  that's only possible for *some* algorithm on an already sorted list.  O(n^2) the best possible?  I seriously doubt it.

Comment: I predict something like insertion sort with 3k entries...